# still can't push to github

Tags: git, github

In my last post ( [Can't push to git hub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13965622/cant-push-to-git-hub) ) I said that I was beginning ch. 2 in Hartl's Ruby on Rails Tutorial. I have gotten every thing in ch. 1 to work and have done everything by the book in ch. 2. But when I try to do:

```
$ git push -u origin master
```

I get the response:

```
ERROR: repository not found
fatal: could not read from remote repository
Please make sure you have the correct access rights and that the repository exists.
```

Since then I have done:

```
ssh -T git@github.com.
```

The response was

```
Hi username! Your have successfully authenticated, etc.
```

I have also done:

```
git remote -v.
```

The response was

```
origin git@github.com:myusername/demo_app.git (fetch)
origin git@github.com:myusername/demo_app.git (push)
```

This seems to me to indicate that everything is OK, but I still get the same error message.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't push to git hub](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13965622/cant-push-to-git-hub)

Answer (score 2):

The error message from your push command says “repository not found”.  That means you haven't created the remote repository on github.

Go to https://github.com/new and create a repository named `demo_app`.